# Why can't cordova find the android build tools

Tags: android, cordova, android-sdk-build-tools

I am attempting to create an android app with Cordova. I have previously installed IntelliJ IDE, which created an `Android` directory in my home folder. Inside, there is an `Sdk` folder, containing `build-tools`, `licenses`, `platform-tools`, `platforms`, and `sources`. My Cordova project is in `Documents/Android`. I have added android as a platform, but when I run `cordova emulate android`, it says `No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version 33.0.2.` I have the correct build tools in my Android SDK directory, and it is in my `$PATH`. I am on a raspberry pi running Ubuntu, so I can't install Android Studio (I tried!). I have tried moving the build tools around my home folder, updating gradle, downgrading it, removing build-tools, reinstalling it, and upgrading Cordova.The full output is:

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_HOME=/home/arco/Android/Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/arco/Android/Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: /home/arco/Android/Sdk
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
openjdk version "11.0.22" 2024-01-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.22+7-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu223.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.22+7-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu223.10.1, mixed mode)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/home/arco/Documents/Android/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle' line: 69

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version 33.0.2.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Command failed with exit code 1: /home/arco/Documents/Android/hello/platforms/android/gradlew -b /home/arco/Documents/Android/hello/platforms/android/build.gradle cdvBuildDebug
```

Comment: Have you opened Android Studio and in it the SDK manager and selected Android build tools version 33.0.2 so that it is getting installed uf missing?

Comment: I am running on a Raspberry Pi, and Android Studio for Linux doesn't support ARM

Comment: Hope you have an RPi5 because building Android apps requires a fast CPU, storage and much RAM. Unfortunately Google does no longer provide an SDK manager for command-line. Thus you have to do everything manually. The necessary directory structure is shown here: https://developer.android.com/tools  The available package download URLs can be found here https://androidsdkmanager.azurewebsites.net/